# Code in my for loop not being executed?

Tags: java, for-loop

Basically, the code runs and just prints out the average and sum as 0 (Probably because I've initialised them to 0) but when I take the zeros out the code errors and tells me that I must initialise them, Is there something wrong with my code? As you can tell by the simple code I am writing, I have just started learning java so please take that into consideration.

Compiler: TextPad

```
int i=1, num1=0, num2=0, num3=0;
int average;
int sum;

for (i=1; i >4; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a number");
    num1 = console.nextInt();
    num2 = console.nextInt();
    num3 = console.nextInt();
}

sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
average = sum/3;

System.out.println("Sum: " +sum);
System.out.println("Average:  " +average);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the loop is that in

```
for (i=1; i >4; i++)
```

you put that i > 4, however that means that the for loop will only execute when i is greater than 4, and this can never occur because you initially set i equal to zero.

The correct thing to do would be to edit it to

```
for (i=1; i < 4; i++)
```

Because then it will execute when variable i is less than the number four, which it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=1; i >4; i++)
```

means:

1. set i to 1
2. is i>4
3. No so don't execute the loop body

i.e. this loop is never executed

Comment: Don't you mean `i < 4`, not `i <= 4`?

Comment: Thanks Peter, feel like a dummy for such a little mistake!